# How to get the top performing employees from each Region?

Tags: sql

I have a table Sales with three columns: **Sales_Rep:** *The name of the sales representative*, **Region**: *denoting the region they work in* and **Total_sales:** Total Sales done by the sales representative.
I want to find only the sales reps with maximum sales in each region. The table has 50 rows.
I tried doing it using self join but no rows are returned.
The SQl code which I have written is:

```
SELECT s1.Sales_Rep, s1.Region,s1.Total_sales
FROM sales s1
JOIN sales s2
ON s1.Sales_Rep = s2.Sales_Rep
WHERE s1.Region = s2.Region 
AND s1.Total_sales > s2.Total_sales
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this?[The table image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaLaV.png)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What's the expected result if a region has two sales representatives with the same, maximum sales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a CTE to get the max sales of each region then joined it back to the original table based on the total sales and region to find the saleperson

```
WITH MAX_CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    REGION,
    MAX(TOTAL_SALES) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM SALES 
GROUP BY REGION
)
SELECT
    *
FROM SALES TABLE1
    JOIN MAX_CTE CTE1 ON CTE1.REGION = TABLE1.REGION AND CTE1.TOTAL_SALES = TABLE1.TOTAL_SALES
```

Comment: If you could tell me why does my SQL code doesn't give any output then it would be really helpful for me. Thanks Again

Comment: Because in your where statement you have where s1.total_sales > s2.sales. If you add s2.sales to your select statement you will notice that they are the same so there would be 0 results that have s1.total_sales > s2.total_sales

Comment: Got it bro. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Where Statement with another Select statement, you'll be sure to get the highest total sales. By using distinct(Region) and Group by Region. The values will be seperated by Region so each will have its own Sales Rep with the highest Total sales.

```sql
    Select Sales_Rep, Region, Total_sales
    FROM sales
    Where Total_sales = (Select max(Total_sales) from sales) 
    GROUP by Region;
```

Edited: The where statement should be stated before the group statement 
Edited2 : Removed Distinct from Select statement

Comment: This code has syntax error. WHERE clause comes before GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And there's no `DISTINCT` function. And the `GROUP BY` is invalid.

Comment: This returns an error, since we have to put all the other columns in GROUP BY clause while aggregating data.